# Having a prop named "value" stops rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a custom input component and if I pass a prop called value then it is not rendering at all, whereas if I change the name of the prop to something other than value then everything is working as expected. I am trying to figure it out for the past several hours but it was fruitless.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Input extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.extractStateFromProps(props);
    this.onChange = e => props.onChange(e.target.value);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
    this.setState(this.extractStateFromProps(nextProps));
  }

  extractStateFromProps (props) {
    const value = props.value;
    return value;
  }

  render () {
    console.log(this.props, this.state);
    return (
      <input
        type={this.props.type}
        value={this.props.value}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        name={this.props.identifier}
      />
    );
  }
}

Input.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.oneOf('text', 'number'),
  value: PropTypes.string,
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  identifier: PropTypes.string
};

export default Input;
```

If I name the prop "text" as "value" then nothing is rendered.

```
      <Input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Recipie Name"
        onChange={this.onRecipeNameChange}
        identifier="recipeName"
        text={this.state.currentRecipe.recipeName}
      />
```

[Link to the source](https://github.com/dhanushuUzumaki/recipe-box/tree/fab23202ac164874c6b58648bcb22c7365c03201)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp element.value is what value in input get bound to. If you mess with that in unintended way the dom object possibly becomes unable to hold the value you told it to and fails to render?

Comment: So does it mean I am not supposed to use the "value" as a prop?

Comment: It means you should be careful what you put there? It's a wild guess. Eg. if you have input but as a value property you try to pass it a function

Comment: But this is a custom component and I am passing value to it, which passed the proptype check for string.

Comment: Your `extractstatefromprops` function is wrong, and mostly useless. You're returning a value, and setting state to that value. State should be an object, not a simple value.

Comment: You seem to be saving `value` to `this.state` and then never using `this.state.value` anywhere. Why are you placing things in `state` if you never read from them later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**That's because when you call `extractStateFromProps` you are returning a string and a local component state must be set to an `object` or `null` or `undefined` never as a simple value**

So when you pass the `text` prop, in :

```
  extractStateFromProps (props) {
    const value = props.value;

    return value;
  }
```

`value` is not defined within in your props object, so the returned value will be `undefined` which is valid as a react `state`.

---

But when you pass `value` as a prop in this case `this.state.currentRecipe.recipeName` which should be a string:

```
  extractStateFromProps (props) {
    const value = props.value;

    return value;
  }
```

the returned value will be a `string` type, something that can't be set as a valid react `state`.

## Solution

You can fix this returning an object in `extractStateFromProps`:

```
  extractStateFromProps (props) {
    const value = props.value;

    return { value };
  }
```

then you can use the input, this way:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Input extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.extractStateFromProps(props);
    this.onChange = e => props.onChange(e.target.value);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
    this.setState(this.extractStateFromProps(nextProps));
  }

  extractStateFromProps (props) {
    const value = props.value;
    return { value };
  }

  render () {
    console.log(this.props, this.state);
    return (
      <input
        type={this.props.type}
        value={this.props.value}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        name={this.props.identifier}
      />
    );
  }
}

Input.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.oneOf('text', 'number'),
  value: PropTypes.string,
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  identifier: PropTypes.string
};

export default Input;
```

```
  <Input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Recipie Name"
    onChange={this.onRecipeNameChange}
    identifier="recipeName"
    value={this.state.currentRecipe.recipeName}
  />
```

Comment: Thanks. So dumb of me :(